# Why does using mtr speed up my download?

Tags: linux, networking

While updating php using homebrew I noticed that if I used `mtr` to ping the source of the file, the download speed would increase dramatically (on the order of 3 - 4 times faster).

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2):

An educated guess: Your provider is cheating you. It is [not unheard of](https://twitter.com/i0n1c/status/223323716816355328) that some providers increase the download speed once the URL contains the word speedtest. Since many speed tests also do a ping test, and a good ping is generally seen as a quality characteristic of a connection, the network equipment might shape the traffic in such a way that you get good ping results, resulting in higher download speeds.

(Another [source](http://www.tech-blog.net/kabel-deutschland-drosselt-geschwindigkeit-auser-bei-speedtests/) for the speedtest URL thing in German)

Obviously, this is not the only possible answer.